# No signature of method is applicable for argument types when trying to publish to JCenter with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jcenter

I'm trying to publish my project to JCenter with gradle.

I'm getting this error:

```
$ ./gradlew bintrayUpload

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/tomcaflisch/my-project/build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'.
> No signature of method: build_1izvkzzfcfkppgubyut54udzf.bintray() is applicable for argument types: (build_1izvkzzfcfkppgubyut54udzf$_run_closure3) values: [build_1izvkzzfcfkppgubyut54udzf$_run_closure3@30577a07]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Here's my `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray" version "1.8.5"
}

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com.projectx'
version = '0.0.1'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
}

bintray {
    user = System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = System.getenv('BINTRAY_KEY')
    publications = ['MyPublication']
    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'project-x'
        userOrg = 'myorg'
        licenses = ['Proprietary']
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/myorg/my-project.git'
        version {
            name = project.version
            released new Date()
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        MyPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            groupId project.group
            artifactId 'projectx'
            version project.version
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.artifactId = 'projectx'
    }
}

test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport   // Report is always generated after tests run
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test  // Tests are required to run before generating the report
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}

task execute(type:JavaExec) {
    main = System.getProperty('mainClass')
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.22'
    compile "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2"
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.14.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    compile 'io.gsonfire:gson-fire:1.8.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.13'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.+'
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1"
}

javadoc {
    options.tags = [ "http.response.details:a:Http Response Details" ]
}
```

Comment: what version of gradle?

Comment: Also what is the output of `project.pluginManager.hasPlugin('com.jfrog.bintray')`?

Comment: Gradle 6.3.0.

Where would I see that output?

Comment: You should be able to print this anywhere inside your `build.gradle`, then simply run `gradle` without arguments to see the output

Answer (score 0):

Bintray is dead.
But to answer the question, `No signature of method: build_whatever.[method]()` comes from something in the configuration of [method] being incorrect. In this case I'd guess it's caused by `released new Date()` which should probably be `released = new Date()`